# jQuery created element cannot be sent through post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically creating input of type text in my form with a value. I can see the new input, but every time I'm sending this through ajax to my php file, it doesn't get the new created input.

The input is put into a table, which is in a form.

I tried with javascript and jQuery, but the two examples **do not use the same data**, because the javascript way was only for testing purpose

## Javascript way

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type","text");
input.setAttribute("name","moi");
input.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
input.setAttribute("value","HEY");

$('#actor_form').append(input);
```

---

## jquery way

```
var r_name = "<td>" + "<input type='text' name='role[]' disabled value=" +$('#role_name').val()+ " ></td>" ;
var a_name = "<td>" + "<input type='text' name='name[]' disabled value=" +$('#actor_list').val()+  "></td>";
var r_gender = "<td>" + "<input type='text' name='gender[]' disabled value=" +$('#role_gender').val()+"></td>";
var tr = a_name + r_name  + r_gender;
    
$('#actor_table').append("<tr>"+tr +"</tr>");
```

---

## Sending of data

```
$.post("assign_roles.php",   $("#actor_form").serialize()  ,function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

---

## PHP file

```
echo $_POST['element'];
```

Comment: What do you expect to get as a result of `echo $_POST`?

Comment: Any element in the form. Its now corrected

Comment: Maybe because you are appending it to `actor_table` and not `actor_form`?

Comment: Are you missing quotes around the value attributes? (value='"+$('#role_name').val()+"')

Comment: @user2040101: it's incorrect. You cannot just `echo` arrays in php. Try `echo array();` and see the result

Answer (score 3):

The inputs are disabled, so they won't be included in the serialized data.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

> "Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string."

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2

> "Controls that are disabled cannot be successful."

Comment: Ohh you are right,but i dont want the user to disable those...so what can i do??

Comment: @user2040101: You can read all the values you want from the form and put in an object, instead of using `serialize`.

Comment: Yea i could do that. But I decide simply to enable before I use $.post and disable them after. all inside the function